# New system, does not boot, 1 long beep two short

Tags: boot, video, graphics-card, motherboard

I bought 970A-G43 motherboard with FX-6300 processor. Hooked everything and plugged in an HD 6950 video card. On boot I get 1 long and 2 short beeps regardless if I plug the video on either of the 2 available PCIe or if I remove it completely. I has got to be a faulty board, right?

Hardware recap:
MB: MSI 970A-G43
CPU: AMD Black Edition - AMD FX 6300 - 3.5 GHz
PSU: Cooler Master 500W
RAM: Corsair Vengeance - Geheugen - 8 GB : 2 x 4 GB
GPU: Radeon HD 6950

Please help!

Comment: What does the manual say the bios beep code means?

Comment: It has to be graphics card error: [Gigabyte: 1 long beep, 2 short beeps](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=816) and [MSI's BIOS beep codes guide](https://forum-en.msi.com/faq/article/bios-beep-codes)

Comment: Did you plug in the power to the video card (from the PSU)? Obvious question but better to ask then to proceed any further.

Comment: Yes the two 6-pin cables for the video were plugged in. The weird thing is I get this beep sequence with the card removed. And I know the card works for sure.

Comment: There was no pc speaker on the board when I bought it, so I used a 4 pin I took from another main board. Maybe it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with exact beep sequences, however I've had an issue two years ago where I've build a pc but it failed to boot, with some beeps on boot. This was due to the RAM not being properly inserted into the slots. From what I remember, nothing displayed on my screen as well. Couldn't even boot to BIOS. Some other issues with RAM may be that your motherboard isn't compatible with the particular RAM which you've selected.

I suggest checking your motherboard's compatibility with your RAM, and try just one RAM into all possible slots, rechecking every slot for proper RAM insertion a few times.